# How to edit this HumanTiming function to display correct plural and non plural forms?

Tags: php

I need to implement this function into my website but however my language requires a bit more modification since it's not as it is in English adding only /s for plural. So, here it is:

```
    Plural form:

    години
    месеци
    седмици
    дни
    часа
    минути
    секунди

Non plural form:

година
месец
седмица
ден
час
минута
секунда
```

So, how I can make that change on the `humanTiming` function below?

```
$time = strtotime('2014-09-22 00:00:00');

echo 'Сървъра стартира преди '.humanTiming($time).'';

function humanTiming ($time)
{

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment

// Non plural forms
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'година',
        2592000 => 'месец',
        604800 => 'седмица',
        86400 => 'ден',
        3600 => 'час',
        60 => 'минута',
        1 => 'секунда'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in the token variable arrays of values, like this:

```
...
31536000 => array('година', 'години'),   // singular, plural1, plural2?...
...
```

In the for loop select the appropriate value based on your number:

```
$text = $numberOfUnits > 1 ? $text[1] : $text[0];
return $numberOfUnits . ' ' . $text;
```

If you're making use of some sort of `gettext` implementation, it most likely comes with a function that handles these kind of things. For example, the gettext PHP extension has [`ngettext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ngettext.php)

Comment: Oh, yeah. Placing them in an `array()` .. Thank you a lot. Answer is accepted!